# What is the correct way to customize a Bootstrap theme?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks

I want to use a Bootstrap theme, but I need customize it. What is the correct way? Should I create a new CSS file to override the default CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, I think there are two steps based on your question.

1. Get used with Bootstrap, the documentation is really good. So before customize it, it's going to be better to understand how it works, at least in a very basic way.
2. Probably the easiest way to customize Bootstrap is though its own [site](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/). There you can change things like general colors, forms, dropdowns, the navbar, etc.

If you have specific questions about it, please let me know.

Comment: thank you @HORACIO. maybe soon i have other question about it. thank you very much

Answer (score 7):

I just wrote a [post](http://betaorbust.com/maintainable-bootstrap-customization/) about how I've been doing it at [Udacity](https://udcity.com) for the last couple years. This method has meant we've been able to update Bootstrap whenever we wanted to without having merge conflicts, thrown out work, etc. etc.

The the post goes more in depth with examples, but the basic idea is:

- Keep a pristine copy of bootstrap and overwrite it externally.
- Modify one file (bootstrap's variables.less) to include your own variables.
- Make your site file @include bootstrap.less and then your overrides.

When it comes time to upgrade your bootstrap, you just swap out the pristine bootstrap copy and everything will still work.

Here's the [post](http://betaorbust.com/maintainable-bootstrap-customization/) with walk-through.

Code example on github is [here](https://github.com/betaorbust/overstrap).

Comment: The link for the post is dead. Here is a link for archive.org. https://web.archive.org/web/20180109002007/https://betaorbust.com/maintainable-bootstrap-customization/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to keep bootstrap files without modifications. That way you can update it to a new version if needed.

So, the correct way to customize is to add your own CSS file (at least during the development process).

Comment: like for example ive downloaded free bootstrap theme and i wan to customize it. I will make a new css file?

Comment: Yes, and load it after the bootstrap.css loag (in the header section of your HTML)

Comment: Then the responsiveness still remain?

Comment: Yes, unless you overwrite rules related to it

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is creating a new main CSS file. You should include bootstrap.css and the other stuff also but editing on bootstrap CSS file may not be a good idea.

Comment: I'm not preferring LESS.

Comment: what is the used of this?

Comment: LESS is making a few things easier but I guess you're a newbie. You should learn more about bootstrap, after that you can decide about LESS stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This has been thoroughly documented. I've seen probably 30 ways to do it. By far one of the most elegant and best solutions I have come across so far is described in [this blogpost](https://medium.com/@markhealey/customizing-bootstrap-the-right-way-5ba8735d87b1).

Exactly the same principle is applied in [this workflow](http://www.wombit.se/2013/11/03/bootstrap-separate-source-customizations/). Just a different setup. Even better if you want to treat Bootstrap as a dependency without touching the source.